# slack - github integration, mentioning/tagging user in github also notify them in slack

Tags: github, integration, slack

i've look at https://my.slack.com/apps/search?q=github and did not find apps that suitable for my needs.

the idea is to notify the user in slack and post the Github url when they were mentioned/tagged in the Github (@username) (similar with when Github sent email notification)

is there a way for a person to be notified in slack?

Comment: No. This isn't straightforward to implement without a webhooks event for a @mention.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people use [MailClark](https://mailclark.ai) to convert email notifications into Slack notifications. When there is a mention in an email, MaiClark recognizes it and converts it as a Slack mention.

So if you link your GitHub notifications to a Slack channel with MailClark, it could work (providing you have the same user name in Slack and in GitHub.) Not sure that it is the best solution, but you still can give it a try!